# what is tool like mycli or pgcli on oracle database?

Tags: oracle, shell, command-line, terminal

Is there any tool like mycli or pgcli for oracle database? Because it is very useful when I'm querying inside terminal, and their autocomplete  feature also help me a lot.

I often use terminal, so I really need this kind of software tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command line tool which comes bundled with Oracle is SQL*Plus. [Find out more.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/doc.112/e12152/toc.htm)

SQL*Plus is now a rather old tool so it doesn't necessarily do everything we'd want in a command line tool, or do things in the most intuitive fashion. Even its name looks old-fashioned. Oracle realise this and have a new product, `sqlcl`. It does lots of neat things (command history, autocompletion, scripting, oh my!) but it is a standalone download and install. [Find out more](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sqlcl/index.html).

Comment: Yes i know about SQL*Plus. but is there an autocomplete feature?

Comment: Nope. For that you need `sqlcl`

Comment: Nice info.. i just already installed the sqlcl, after read & show preview video about it. Thanks man

Comment: SQLcl does ship with latest database installs.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a general wrapper: GNU SQL http://www.gnu.org/s/parallel/sql.html